# Turn text into hyperlink on the frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, woocommerce

Right now author's profile link is being outputted as a text on the frontend, but I want it to be outputted as hyperlink. So only text is being outputted: example.com/author/username. I need to turn this into hyperlink - to display a username associated with a user_link and to be clickable(to actually take you associated example.com/author/username.

I'm outputting this author profile information through shortcode on the frontend.

In my shortcode.php file it's defined like this at moment(Author's profile link is being pulled from a saved order.):

```
$output .= '<td>' . $order->user_link . '</td>';
```

`user_link` is outputting just a text format: example.com/author/username on the frontend. I need a hyperlink and I don't know how to create a hyperlink for this.

Answer (score 0):

The function you need to use is [get_the_author_link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_link)

Comment: No, I'm pulling out the saved value and need to turn it into hyperlink.

Comment: The saved value is the author id?

Comment: It's the author link: 
    `$user_link = home_url( '/author/' . $user->user_login );`

Comment: So you want to display the `$user_link` as a hyperlink? correct me if i'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
$output .= "<td> <a href='" . $order->user_link . " '>user</a></td>";
```

can't you change your shortcode.php into this. correct me if i am wrong .I am not sure about it.